# Excerpt all post content Content Same Size without word cutting off

Tags: php, posts, loop, excerpt, the-content

On my category page there are list of 24 posts with title and excerpt content.

To display specific lengths of content, I am using **substr**  function. Now the issue is that each post excerpt content are displaying in different lengths.

To display specific lengths of content I am using substr to cut string  of specific length.

```
  $content = strip_tags(get_the_content());

  $content = substr($content, 0, 100);

  echo $content . '[..]';
```

for example:

```
      post title one
     post content size post content size post content size post content 
     size post content size[..]

   post title two
   post content 1'50" 0 size post content 55 size post content th[..]

   post title three
   post content size post "content 55" size checkk post content s[..]
```

Here in example you can see each post has different content lenght. Now what I am looking for is each post display specific lenght of content.

Second and third post content lengths should be same as **first post.**  Also spelling should not cut.

For that I've tried

```
     $words = explode(' ', $string, ($word_limit + 1));

    if(count($words) > $word_limit) {

   array_pop($words);
  //add a ... at last article when more than limit word count
  echo implode(' ', $words)."..."; } else {
 //otherwise
 echo implode(' ', $words); }
```

but it is not working .

I need help to display same length content without word cut off.

Comment: Why are you not using `the_excerpt()` to display your content. Is there another issue with `the_excerpt()`

Comment: not using the_excerpt because i am using the_excerpt on custom post type page to cut different size of content. that is why i am using substr for category page.

Comment: do you mean to say if i had used the_except then all the post's content will display in same length and words will not cut off?

Comment: Jip, but check my answer, more flexible

Answer (score 0):

I use [`wp_trim_words`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_trim_words) to create multiple excerpts. I always abuse it when I need more than one excerpt length. Here is how

```
function wpse_custom_excerpts($limit) {
    return wp_trim_words(get_the_excerpt(), $limit, '<a href="'. esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '">' . '&nbsp;&hellip;' . __( 'Read more &nbsp;&raquo;', 'wpse' ) . '</a>');
}
```

What this function do is taking [`get_the_excerpt`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_excerpt) trimming that to `$limit` set by the user and returning the text with a read more link at the end.

You can call this excerpt as follow in your template

```
echo wpse_custom_excerpts($limit);
```

where `$limit` will be your word count, so an excerpt of 30 word will be

```
echo wpse_custom_excerpts(30);
```

Comment: Any specific reason why this question is still open? Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and [Why is voting important?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote). Thank you